# SQL Table parameter, filter rows to insert

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following procedure that uses a user defined table parameter `@Till_Sales`:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Create_Batch_Till_Sales]
    @Till_Sales [dbo].Till_Sale_Insert READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO Till_Sale (Site_Lookup_Id, Client_Transaction_Date, Client_EOD_Id, Client_Id, Operator, PLU, Unit_Price, Quantity, Terminal_Id, Unit_Multiplier, Create_Date)
        SELECT 
            tbl.Site_Lookup_Id, tbl.Client_Transaction_Date, 
            tbl.Client_EOD_Id, tbl.Client_Id, tbl.Operator, tbl.PLU, 
            tbl.Unit_Price, tbl.Quantity, tbl.Terminal_Id, 
            tbl.Unit_Multiplier, GETDATE() 
        FROM 
            @Till_Sales AS tbl;
END
```

Is there a way to amend this so that I can only insert rows from the parameter table (`@Till_Sales`) that currently don't exist in the `Till_Sale` table? I would be using `Client_Id` column as a unique identifier in this instance. SQL isn't my strongest suit.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Create_Batch_Till_Sales]

@Till_Sales [dbo].Till_Sale_Insert READONLY
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

INSERT INTO Till_Sale (Site_Lookup_Id, Client_Transaction_Date, Client_EOD_Id, Client_Id, Operator, PLU, Unit_Price, Quantity, Terminal_Id, Unit_Multiplier, Create_Date)
        SELECT tbl.Site_Lookup_Id, tbl.Client_Transaction_Date, tbl.Client_EOD_Id, tbl.Client_Id, tbl.Operator, tbl.PLU, tbl.Unit_Price, tbl.Quantity, tbl.Terminal_Id, tbl.Unit_Multiplier, GETDATE() 
        FROM @Till_Sales AS tbl
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Till_Sale WHERE Till_Sale.Client_Id  = tbl.Client_Id)


END
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to sort it like so... been a long day, not sure why I didn't see it sooner!

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Create_Batch_Till_Sales]

@Till_Sales [dbo].Till_Sale_Insert READONLY
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

INSERT INTO Till_Sale (Site_Lookup_Id, Client_Transaction_Date, Client_EOD_Id, Client_Id, Operator, PLU, Unit_Price, Quantity, Terminal_Id, Unit_Multiplier, Create_Date)
        (SELECT tbl.Site_Lookup_Id, tbl.Client_Transaction_Date, tbl.Client_EOD_Id, tbl.Client_Id, tbl.Operator, tbl.PLU, tbl.Unit_Price, tbl.Quantity, tbl.Terminal_Id, tbl.Unit_Multiplier, GETDATE() 
         FROM @Till_Sales AS tbl 
         WHERE tbl.Client_Id NOT IN (SELECT Client_Id FROM Till_Sale));

END
```